# EF Remove Related Classes on Object Load

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm querying my database using EF DB first and i have my "news" area that is linked to several other areas and i don't want to load the relationships of this object. What options do i have to do it ? I'm working with WebApi 2 and returning the data as JSON to my application.

I know some options that i have tried:

1. Create a second class with the fields i want and map it using the LINQ select;
2. Remove them manually setting them as null.

I don't really like those options because the second one doesn't sounds right and the first one feels like redoing work and i was wondering if there's a better option to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options here are probably:

1. Make DTOs specific for your "news" area, that will contain only information, that you need to return, use some kind of Mapper to map from your Entity to your DTO. I would recommend that method as it gives you enough flexibility to make your API contract and DB Schema not depend on each other heavily.
2. Disable Lazy-loading either system-wide or for this specific relationship removing `virtual` keyword and using `.Include(x=>x.Navigation)` where you explicitely need those properties.

Comment: I like your first option, i'm using a mix of it with AutoMapper. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to turn off Lazy Loading 
this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

and turn off Proxy Creation 
this.Configuration.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

Then make sure NOT to use an Include in your LINQ query.  HTH

Comment: That sounds good, if i wanted to make an include on here: `var comunicado = await _context.Comunicado.FindAsync(id);`. How could i do it ? Also, do i need to turn it back on at the end of my method ?

Comment: _context.Comunicado.Include("news").FindAsync(id)

Remember that the include value is from the Navigation Name at the bottom of each Entity in the Entity Framework.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708(v=vs.110).aspx